# Checking if OracleParameter.Value is Null without doing ToString conversion

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I have a stored procedure which has some `OUT` parameters. On the .NET side I'm perplexed about how to check if the parameter is null before converting it to a .NET `Double?`. I've done this sort of thing a lot before across several different projects and I've never encountered this issue before...

This is every combination I've tried:

```vb
Command.Parameters.Add("PparStsValue", OracleDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

PparStsValue = If(IsDBNull(Command.Parameters("PparStsValue").Value) OrElse
                  IsNothing(Command.Parameters("PparStsValue").Value) OrElse
                  Command.Parameters("PparStsValue").Value.ToString = "",
               Nothing,
               CDbl(Command.Parameters("PparStsValue").Value.ToString))
```

There is one other thing I've done which does work, but it just seems ridiculous which is to check:

`Command.Parameters("PparStsValue").Value.ToString = "null"`

This evaluates to `True` and therefore I can identify nulls... But why does a null value convert to the string `"null"`? That seems so inconsistent with everything else which usually converts to `""`.

That aside, the main question is why don't either `IsDBNull` and `IsNothing` return true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ODP your parameter does not automatically return CLR type but rather oracle type. So the way to do it for numeric `OracleParameter` is this

```vb
Dim oraDec as OracleDecimal = 
    DirectCast(Command.Parameters("PparStsValue").Value, OracleDecimal)

Dim dbl as Double
If Not oraDec.IsNull Then 
    dbl = Convert.ToDouble(oraDec.Value)
End If
```

Comment: That does work, thank you. I still don't really understand why I've never had to do that before but oh well.

Comment: @WSC Good. When you say, "before". What do you mean? What have you've done before? May be, before, something was different? Different provider, different parameter usage, etc?

Comment: My original code used to just be `IsNothing(Command.Parameters("PparStsValue").Value) OrElse Command.Parameters("PparStsValue").Value.ToString = ""` and this worked. I'm thinking now that I might have updated either the .NET Framework version or the ODP.NET version since it was working and one of those changed the `ToString` method to convert null values into `"null"` rather than `""`.

Comment: Well. We can start that you shouldn't use `IsNothing` on `parameter.value` because... and this is the reason WHY it "worked". Because `Value` gets you a **value type**. Or, `DbNull.value`. So in your previous circumstance you probably retrieved a `DbNull.Value`, which would give you `DbNull.Value.ToString() = String.Empty`. This is bad approach from the start  -to call `ToString()` on your return value unless it is string. If your code specific to a call you know exactly your expected type. Code that covers all types, should check `if dbnull, if is nothing, if oracleDate, if oraclestring` etc

Comment: @WSC But don't use `IsNothing`. This is VB compatibility functions. Use `is nothing` or `isnot nothing`. Will help you when eventually you will endup converting to c#